# Identify if a file uses BER encoding

Tags: encoding, asn.1

I'm new to ASN.1 encoding, and I'm wondering if a BER encoded file has a header or anything that identifies it as a BER encoded file.  I mean, if someone just hands me a file, could I tell that it is BER (or CER or DER) encoded?

Then I could have a function that operated like this:

```
if FILE is BER-encoded
  return "BER"
else if FILE is DER-encoded
  return "DER"
else
  return "It's something else"
```

But I'm not sure if BER encoding works that way, or if you have to have something to decode it with before you even know if it's BER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special header that would identify a BER encoding. However, there is a lot of redundancy in the format so that you can identify many byte sequences as not valid BER if you analyse them fully.

Every DER encoding is also a valid BER encoding, but not necessarily the other way round. you could read a byte sequence as BER and then reencode the abstract value with DER and check if you got the same result. If yes, it was originally DER.

Comment: To encode DER, you need the schema.  If you have the schema in the first place, you would be able to verify whether the data was valid DER or merely BER.  Note that DER just removes encoding options that BER allows, so that a given value can only be encoded one way.

Answer (score 1):

As @Henry says, there is no special header.

However, you can know if your file contains BER encoded data by trying to decode them.

Go to http://asn1-playground.oss.com/, make sure `BER` is checked, select `Binary file` in the `Data` dropdown (upper right box) and upload your binary file.

If your file contains valid BER encoded data, it will show in the `CONSOLE OUTPUT`

However, you may be disappointed by the result: even if it is valid, you may not see any useful information (you need the schema, aka specification, to understand the data).

Comment: Note that trying to decode without a schema will only tell you whether a) the data is definitely not BER or b) the data could be BER.  Generally, you wouldn't be able to say the data is definitely BER because a generic decoding can only go so far without the schema.

Comment: @Kevin Let me question the "a" statement: if it's a valid BER encoding, but to decode it you require a  schema which you don't have - that situation looks indistinguishable from just a non-BER data.

Comment: @Illya Etingof  I think we're on the same page.  I meant that when decoding without a schema, the most you could say is either a) data is definitely not BER or b) data could be BER.  You generally would't be able to conclude c) data definitely is BER, because sometimes you really need the schema.